# local users accessing the same folder from rstudio-server

Tags: ubuntu, users, samba

I´m a Linux-Beginner and managed to install Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and R, as well as Rstudio-Server on a PC that i use for data analysis. I can use rstudio-server on this PC through the browser of my laptop.

Nonw i want to give another person access to the rstudio-server and my files, but it´s not possible to use the same rstudio-session (the other person would be kicked out). So i made two local users and now i want the second user to have full access on my home-folder, were my data is stored.

What i tried: 
First i added both users to a group and gave them all permissions to the folder. But in rstudio-server i only see the home-folder of the second local user. 
Second, i figured out it could be done with samba. I installed samba and added this to /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[share]
comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
path = /home/user1/
browsable = yes
valid users = user1, user2
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0755
```

the i opened etc/fstab and put this inside

```
//home/user1/myfolder  /home/user2/myfolder  cifs  username=user2,password=user2pw
```

but i got an error-message

> mount error(2): No such file or directory
>   Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

A third idea i just had: Can i just change the home directory of user2 to the folder of user1?

You see, i don´t really know how to get there, as i´m at the beginning of my learning-curve with linux. Perhaps you can help me out? I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, i found the answer shortly after posting the question.

I just made an symbolic link:

```
ln -s <source_file_directory> <link_file_directory>
```

and it worked.

But you´ll still have to give the second user permissions to the source-folder.